# Base Unit Test Class best practices

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, nunit, solid-principles

I'm writing unit test for Business Layer (Service Classes) of ASP.Net Core. These service classes use Repositories to deal with DB. So I need to create a base test class to share all redundant work as the following:

```
    [TestFixture]
    public abstract class ServiceTestBase<TService, TEntity>
        where TService : IGenericService<TEntity>
        where TEntity : BaseEntity
    {
        #region [Mocks]
        protected Mock<IGenericRepository<TEntity>> repo;
        protected Mock<ILogger<TEntity>> logger;
        #endregion

        #region [Fields]
        protected TService service;
        protected IMapper mapper;
        #endregion

        #region [Setup]
        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public virtual void OneTimeSetUp()
        {
            mapper = CreateAutoMapper();
            logger = new Mock<ILogger<TEntity>>();

            logger.Setup(l => l.IsEnabled(It.IsAny<LogLevel>()))
                .Returns(true);
        }

        [SetUp]
        public abstract void SetUp();
        #endregion

        #region [Protected]
        protected Mock<IGenericRepository<T>> CreateMockedGenericRepo<T>(ref List<T> fakeDataList)
            where T : BaseEntity, new()
        {
            var affectedRowsCount = 1;
            var repo = new Mock<IGenericRepository<T>>();
            var list = fakeDataList;

            repo.Setup(r => r.FindBy(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<T, bool>>>()))
                .Returns<Expression<Func<T, bool>>, Expression<Func<T, object>>[]>((predicate, includes) => Task.FromResult(list.FirstOrDefault(predicate.Compile())));

            repo.Setup(r => r.GetAll(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<T, bool>>>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Expression<Func<T, object>>[]>()))
            .Returns<Expression<Func<T, bool>>, string, Expression<Func<T, object>>[]>((predicate, sort, includes) => Task.FromResult(list.Where(predicate.Compile())));

            repo.Setup(r => r.GetAll(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<T, bool>>>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Expression<Func<T, object>>[]>()))
            .Returns<Expression<Func<T, bool>>, int, int, string, Expression<Func<T, object>>[]>((predicate, take, skip, sort, includes) => Task.FromResult(list.Where(predicate.Compile()).Take(take).Skip(skip)));

            repo.Setup(r => r.Add(It.IsAny<T>()))
                .Callback<T>(newEntity => list.Add(newEntity));

            repo.Setup(r => r.Update(It.IsAny<T>()))
                .Callback<T>(entity =>
                {
                    list.RemoveAll(e => e.Id == entity.Id);
                    list.Add(entity);
                });

            repo.Setup(r => r.AddOrUpdate(It.IsAny<T>(), It.IsAny<Expression<Func<T, bool>>>()))
                .Callback<T, Expression<Func<T, bool>>>((entity, predicate) =>
                {
                    list.RemoveAll(e => e.Id == entity.Id); list.Add(entity);
                }); 

            repo.Setup(r => r.Delete(It.IsAny<T>()))
                .Callback<T>(entity => list.RemoveAll(e => e.Id == entity.Id));

            repo.Setup(r => r.Count(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<T, bool>>>()))
                .Returns(Task.FromResult(list.Count));

            repo.Setup(r => r.Save())
                .Returns(Task.FromResult(affectedRowsCount));

            return repo;
        }
        #endregion

        #region [Private]
        private IMapper CreateAutoMapper()
        {
            var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(opt => opt.AddProfile<AppMappingProfile>());
            mapperConfig.CompileMappings();
            mapperConfig.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

            return mapperConfig.CreateMapper();
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

And this test sample for Service class:

```
public class EmployeeServiceTests : ServiceTestBase<EmployeeService, Employee>
{
    #region [Fields]

    List<Employee> employees;
    List<User> users;

    #endregion

    #region [Mocks]

    Mock<IGenericRepository<User>> userRepo;

    #endregion

    #region [Setup]

    [SetUp]
    public override void SetUp()
    {
        employees = new List<Employee>
        {
            new Employee {Id = 1, Name = "Employee1" },
            new Employee {Id = 2, Name = "Employee2" },
            new Employee {Id = 3, Name = "Employee3" }
        };

        users = new List<User>
        {
            new User {Id  = 1, UserName = "User1", Password = "P@$$w0rd", CreationDate = DateTime.Now, IsActive = false },
            new User {Id  = 2, UserName = "User2", Password = "P@$$w0rd", CreationDate = DateTime.Now, IsActive = true },
            new User {Id  = 3, UserName = "User3", Password = "P@$$w0rd", CreationDate = DateTime.Now, IsActive = true },
        };

        repo = CreateMockedGenericRepo(ref employees);
        userRepo = CreateMockedGenericRepo(ref users);

        service = new EmployeeService(repo.Object, userRepo.Object, mapper, logger.Object);
    }
    #endregion

    #region [SearchForEmployee Tests]
    [Test]
    public void SearchForEmployee_ReturnsSuccessResponse_WhenNoErrors()
    {
        // Arrange
        var searchInput = new SearchInputDto { SearchKey = "user1", PageNumber = 1, PageSize = 10 };

        // Act
        var serviceResponse = service.SearchForEmployee(searchInput).Result;
        var employeesDtos = mapper.Map<List<EmployeeDto>>(employees);
        employeesDtos.AddRange(mapper.Map<List<EmployeeDto>>(users.Where(r => r.IsActive)));

        // Assert
        repo.Verify(repo => repo.GetAll(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Employee, bool>>>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Employee, object>>[]>()), Times.Once);
        userRepo.Verify(repo => repo.GetAll(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<User, bool>>>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Expression<Func<User, object>>[]>()), Times.Once);

        Assert.That(serviceResponse.Success, Is.EqualTo(true));
        Assert.That(serviceResponse.Errors.Count, Is.EqualTo(0));
        Assert.That(serviceResponse.PagesCount, Is.EqualTo(1));
        Assert.That(serviceResponse.Result, Is.EquivalentTo(employeesDtos));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

My question: Is using this **ServiceTestBase** bad practice or violates the SOLID principles because I call **CreateMockedGenericRepo** method in **Setup** method and setup all repository methods which not all of them aren't needed but I did that to avoid a lot of redundant code. Also are there any comments about my unit test sample or enhancement?

Comment: Instead of *deriving* from `serviceTestBase`, why not just *reference* it, e.g. by a field or a property? Favour compisition over inheritance. Tests hardly fall into something that applies to an inheritance-hierarchy. What you want is just have some utility-methods availiable on all your tests, which can be achieved by compisition far easier.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I agree with you. But what about CreateMockedGenericRepo method? is it good practice or you have some comments about it?

Comment: that´s a pretty opinion-based question, in particular as I don´t know what this method is supposed to do and thus it´s hard to suggest something that may be better - whatever "better" means here.

Comment: @HimBromBeere It's a method to create mocked object of Repository of specified type and setup all method of this mocked Repository which avoids rewriting this mocking in each service. Only concern I've about it that it returns mocked object has all methods even these methods aren't needed. Is it a really reasonable concern?

Comment: This question may be more appropriate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/